# Javascript not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a code in javascript. The code works fine in IE, Chrome and safari but firefox gives problems. Nearly every javascript function of mine fails to work in firefox. Below is the sample code of mine.

```
function changelink(str)
{
    str.className="cpageitem";
    str.href='#';
}
```

The function is wiritten in a seperate javascript file. It is called as soon as the page loads.

```
<body onload='changelink(home)'>
```

What's the possible problem?

Comment: please, provide more information. How do you call it? What argument are you passing? How do you obtain this argument? etc etc etc.

Comment: how about using firebug to identify the problem that always helps me, and maybe you can post the error if it gives you one

Comment: the calling function is like this: <body onload='changelink(str)'>

Comment: how do you obtain home? try to use firebug as @chermosillo said, and do a console.log(home). That'll reveal your error.

Comment: @Gonzalo Larralde: what's firebug? do i need to install it? where do i find it?

Comment: also do you ever initialize home as a variable before the onload event? have you tried to put a init function where you define it and then call changelink?

Comment: @chermosillo: I didn't get what you are saying? Are you trying to tell like this: var str=str and then use it?

Comment: Could we see the rest of your code? Also, have you accidentally commented things out? I know some browsers will executed commented code on occasion, while others won't.

Comment: @Salem: <body onload='changelink(home)'> The output is nothing with an error home not defined

Comment: @Salem: I tried to install firebug but it says its not compatible with the browser. My ff version is 3.0.4

Comment: @Andrew Sorry about that. As you can tell by my rep, I'm a little new here.
@Sanket Firebug is a web development plugin for firefox that lets you see what's "going on under the hood" as the page loads and runs.
[getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/)
Open that in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function changelink(str)
            {
                str.className="cpageitem";
                str.href='#';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload='changelink(home)'>
    <a name="home" href="http://www.nohouse.net">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I write a demo code to reproduce your issue, maybe you missed to add id for "Home".
This issue is caused by IE handles tag name which did not add an id attribute in it's global context, but chrom/FF did not do this, so your sample "home" is not a valid ref to the link you want to modify in the DOM.

You can change it like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function changelink(str)
            {
                str.className="cpageitem";
                str.href='#';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload='changelink(home)'>
    <a id="home" name="home" href="http://www.nohouse.net">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But this may be not the best solution, you should get the DOM object and then use it, do not use the id attribute as the DOM ref in global context. Just suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this

```
function init(){
    var home = document.getElementById('some_anchor_id'); 
    changelink(home);
}
```

then use

```
<body onload="init()">
```